# Proxy issues on git and ssh - Arch linux

Tags: linux, git, ssh, proxy, archlinux

The company I work at recently removed proxy from the network.

I am not able make git forget the proxy. It still uses the old proxy settings.

I have tried:

```
git config --system --unset https.proxy
git config --system --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Also tried,

```
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Output of git config -l

```
user.name=my.name
user.email=my.email.address
user.user=my.name
core.autocrlf=input
```

I am using Manjaro Linux(Arch Linux based). I removed proxy settings from /etc/environment.

The only thing that works is doing

```
export https_proxy=""
export http_proxy=""
```

before issuing any git command.

There are no proxy settings given in bashrc or in /etc/profile.

I am not able to ssh either.

Browser, Maven and others work fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post the verbose log from the `ssh` command (`ssh -vvv`). What errors you see?

Comment: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "{ip address}" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {ip address} port 22. Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host {ip address} port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Have you restarted after `/etc/environment` change? how about `~/.profile`. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.pam_environment`?

Comment: also verify the output of `git config -l` if it contains any proxy mentions or not and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had been bugging me for sometime. I had the feeling that the moment I asked it, I would find an answer.

Turns out there is another file used by Arch Linux for proxy that only a few applications use. The proxy settings in this file is not system wide and that is why I was able to use the browser and other applications after removing proxy in /etc/environment.

There is a file

```
/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

which had the proxy settings. Deleting that and restarting fixed the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you'd probably want to accept this as an answer, so this question would be marked as answered.

Comment: @eis Done. Thank you for yourhelp.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to do is to issue `git config --list` (short version is `git config -l`) to see if it has been configured to git or not.

If it is, go through `~/.gitconfig`, `.git/config` (in repo), `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`, `$GIT_DIR/config` to see where the configuration is and remove it.

If it is not, as I would guess for `http_proxy` unsetting fixing it, go through `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.pam_environment` and remove proxy-defining entries, in addition to `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `.bashrc` you say you already did.

Comment: `git config --list` does not show any proxy. `~/.gitconfig` same as `git config -l`. Only core, remote and branch info in `.git/config` in repo. No file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` and `$GIT_DIR/config`. No `~/.profile file`. No mention of proxy in `/etc/profile`. No proxy configuration in `~/.bash_profile`. No file `~/.pam_environment`. I also tried restarting. Updated the output of `git config --list` in question.